# Question: What is the best DB structure when adding follow/followers feature?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design

I have an app with the following DB structure currently, it uses Firebase Database and is on Swift IOS:

```
  "Posts" : {
"Dm8iyaXXdTOJGsymEiLNVO6OdDK2" : {
  "post:570915537" : {
    "Media" : {
      "image" : {
        "mediaUrl" : "https://firebaseURL",
        "postTimeStamp" : 5.70915539085856E8,
        "timeStamp" : 5.7091551482329E8
      }, ...
```

I was now going to add followers to it. I was thinking that I would either add a whole new group:

```
  "Followers" : {
"Dm8iyaXXdTOJGsymEiLNVO6OdDK2" : {
  "Following" : {
    follower1: "Dm8iyaXXdTOJGsymEiLNVO6OdDK2";
    //other followers
  }, ...
```

Or add a new node to the original group and add them there. The last option is to do something similar to what is done above but in the "Users" section.

**What is the best course of action?**

Comment: With NoSQL databases, the "best" structure is the one that satisfies the speicifc queries you need to build your app.

Comment: @dougstevenson we are using firebase

Comment: Firebase has two database systems, Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore.  Both are NoSQL type databases.

Comment: I removed the ios and swift tags here, because your question has nothing to do with either of those.

Answer (score 4):

A follow/unfollow schema using Firestore could be this one:
2 roots collections, one that holds **users** and another one that holds the **following relationship** between users through a composite key.

```
users/{userID}
  .. userData
  .. followerCount
  .. followedCount


following/{followerID_followedID}
  .. followerId
  .. followedId
  .. createdAt
```

When a userA starts to follow a userB:

- set a new document with the id **userAuid_userBuid** in the
  **following** collection.
- triggers a Cloud Function that will run a transaction to update the
  counters of both users.

Do the reverse thing when a user stops to follow another user.

In the client, you can know if userA follows userB simply by checking if the document userAuid_userBuid exists inside the **following** collection.
You can also get the list of a user's followers by querying the collection where the followedId == the current user Id.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: whats the `createdAt` in the following node!?